# Passing cv::Point array as argument

Tags: c++, arguments

I'm trying my very best to pass a cv::Point array as an argument to a function through a header file. I keep getting errors when I try to build it. I've tried to pass it directly and as a pointer with no success.

This is the error that comes when passing as pointer:

> error: undefined reference to `objDistanceCalc(cv::Point_*, int,
>   int)'

This is the function call in my opencv_test.cpp file containing the main function.

```
#include "stereo_calc.h"
...
Point pos[4];
...
double dist = objDistanceCalc(pos, src_width_half, src_hight);
...
```

Header file stereo_calc.h:

```
#ifndef STEREO_CALC_H
#define STEREO_CALC_H

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

double objDistanceCalc(cv::Point*, int, int);

#endif // STEREO_CALC_H
```

stereo_cam.cpp

```
#include "stereo_calc.h"
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

// Calculates distance to an object given two similar positions on two stereo images
double objDistanceCalc(cv::Point* positions[4], int pixel_width, int pixel_hight)
{
  double D;   // distance
  double b = 41.4;   // distance between stereo cameras (41.4mm for leopard mounted 27.04.2018)
  double f = 2.8;   // focal length [mm] (~2.8mm for leopard, datasheet)
  double x1, x2;  // position distance from center in the left and right camera

  return(D);
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? The code builds good when i remove the objDistanceCalc function from the main file.

Comment: `cv::Point* positions[4]` is not the same as `cv::Point *`. If you want to send in 4 positions, change it to `cv::Point positions[4]` or `cv::Point * positions`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :)